# Regular Expression to match a quoted string embedded in another quoted string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a data source that is comma-delimited, and quote-qualified.  A CSV.  However, the data source provider sometimes does some wonky things.  I've compensated for all but one of them (we read in the file line-by-line, then write it back out after cleansing), and I'm looking to solve the last remaining problem when my regex-fu is pretty weak.

**Matching a Quoted String inside of another Quoted String**

So here is our example string...

```
"foobar", 356, "Lieu-dit "chez Métral", Chilly, FR", "-1,000.09", 467, "barfoo", 1,345,456,235,231, "935.18"
```

I am looking to match the substring **"chez Métral"**, in order to replace it with the substring **chez Métral**.  Ideally, in as few lines of code as possible.  The final goal is to write the line back out (or return it as a method return value) with the replacement already done.

So our example string would end up as...

```
"foobar", 356, "Lieu-dit chez Métral, Chilly, FR", "-1,000.09", 467, "barfoo", 1,345,456,235,231, "935.18"
```

I know I could define a pattern such as `(?<quotedstring>\"\w+[^,]+\")` to match quoted strings, but my regex-fu is weak (database developer, almost never use C#), so I'm not sure how to match another quoted string within the named group **quotedstring**.

---

*FYI: For those noticing the large integer that is formatted with commas but not quote-qualified, that's already handled.  As is the random use of row-delimiters (sometimes CR, sometimes LF).  As other problems...*

Comment: Looks like you have a very badly formed attempt at a CSV file (it is not valid CSV). Regex is not likely to be a good solution for this.

Comment: A->"A"|a is a CF grammar and can't be matched correctly with Regular Expressions.

Comment: How are you "already handling" the embedded commas and "other problems"? Can this same method be used to handle the extra quotes?

Comment: @Oded I agree!  Unfortunately I can't convince the data provider of this.  :)  This is not a common case, but it crops up once in a while with this data source.  Out of 7,000 source files, we have 38 occurrences within 14 files.  We don't have instances where there is arbitrarily deep nesting, either -- it's always one-level deep.  Right now the offending lines are just getting binned by an exception-handler to be processed later.

Comment: Is ", " (comma-space) the separator? Or is it possible that a ", " could be included within a quoted string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with this `regex`

```
(?<!,\s*|^)"([^",]*)"
```

now replace it with `$1`

try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

---

escaping `"` with `""` it would become

```
(?<!,\s*|^)""([^"",]*)""
```

Comment: It appears that with the above pattern ", 356, " and ", 1,345,456,235,231, " are also matches in addition to "chez Métral".

Comment: @TheLazyDBA it doesnt appear that way cuz i have tested it..it works

Comment: Would it be possible for you to further embellish your answer?

Comment: It does work, unfortunately my example string was incorrect so your solution isn't applicable!  /facepalm

Comment: I have.  The example string is accurate.

Comment: Thanks!  In the past week I've had to learn some Python, write a reporting site scraper, re-familiarize myself with C# (I'm mostly just T-SQL and PL/SQL), deal with XSLT for the first time... but regexps? I had a limit as to how quick I could pick up more advanced constructs in such a short span of time.  Appreciated!